# Read stdin in chunks in Bash pipe

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have some shell scripts that works with pipes like such:

```
foo.sh | bar.sh
```

My `bar.sh` calls some command line program that can only take a certain number of lines of stdin. Thus, I want `foo.sh`'s large stdout to be chunked up in N number of lines to make multiple `bar.sh` calls. Essentially, paginate `foo.sh`'s stdout and do multiple `bar.sh`.

Is it possible? I am hoping for some magic in between the pipes like `foo.sh | ??? | bar.sh`. `xargs -n` doesn't quite get me what I want.

Comment: `program that can only take a certain number of lines of stdin` What do you want to do with the remaining `stdin` in the pipe? discard it? If yes, you can possibly use [`head`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/head/) command.

Comment: @anishsane He wants to call `bar.sh` repeatedly with batches of lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am nowhere near a machine to test this, but you need `GNU Parallel` to make this easy - along the lines of:

```
foo.sh | parallel --pipe -N 10000 -k bar.sh
```

As an added bonus, that will run as many `bar.sh` in parallel as you have CPU cores.

Add `-j 1` if you only want one `bar.sh` at a time.

Add `--dry-run` if you want to see what it would do but without doinng anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while read` loop.

```
foo.sh | while read line1 && read line2 && read line3; do
    printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "$line1" "$line2" "$line3" | bar.sh
done
```

For large N, write a function that loops.

```
read_n_lines() {
    read -r line || return 1
    echo "$line"
    n=$(($1 - 1))
    while [[ $n -gt 0 ]] && read -r line; do
        echo "$line"
        n=$((n-1))
    done
}
```

Then you can do:

```
n=20
foo.sh | while lines=$(read_n_lines $n); do
    printf "%s\n" "$lines" | bar.sh
done
```

Comment: This is close, but my N is a large number, and while it is feasible to write a `while` condition with N predicates, I would rather not. Is it possible to not have to write N predicates?

Comment: @StephenChu I've added a function that reads and echoes N lines at a time.