# Send output from `split` utility to stdout

Tags: bash, split, stdout

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines), I found the `split` utilty, which takes a file and splits it into evenly sized chunks. By default, it outputs these chunks to new files, but I'd like to get it to output them to stdout, separated by a newline (or an arbitrary delimiter). Is this possible?

I tried `cat testfile.txt | split -b 128 - /dev/stdout`

which fails with the error `split: /dev/stdoutaa: Permission denied`.

Looking at the help text, it seems this tells split to use /dev/stdout as a *prefix* for the filename, not to write to /dev/stdout itself. It does not indicate any option to write directly to a single file with a delimiter. Is there a way I can trick `split` into doing this, or is there a different utility that accomplishes the behavior I want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38630451/2836621

Comment: `cat file | split` -->  `< file split ...` or `split < file ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want to do, but perhaps the `--filter` option to `split` will help out:

```
   --filter=COMMAND
          write to shell COMMAND; file name is $FILE
```

Maybe you can use that directly.  For example, this will read a file 10 bytes at a time, passing each chunk through the `tr` command:

```
split -b 10 --filter "tr [:lower:] [:upper:]" afile
```

If you really want to emit a stream on *stdout* that has separators between chunks, you could do something like:

```
split -b 10 --filter 'dd 2> /dev/null; echo ---sep---' afile
```

If `afile` is a file in my current directory that looks like:

```
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

Then the above command will result in:

```
the quick ---sep---
brown fox ---sep---
jumped ove---sep---
r the lazy---sep---
 dog.
---sep---
```

Comment: The last example is the behavior I was going for. Though this works, I eventually found it easier to allow split to produce new files as it normally does, then loop through them, then delete them.

Answer (score 3):

From info page :
`--filter=COMMAND'
     With this option, rather than simply writing to each output file,
     write through a pipe to the specified shell COMMAND for each
     output file.  COMMAND should use the $FILE environment variable,
     which is set to a different output file name for each invocation
     of the command.

```
split -b 128 --filter='cat ; echo ' inputfile
```

Comment: Split stdout: <command> | split -b 64 --filter="cat;echo" - 
'cat' is to print the split chunk and 'echo' is to add a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it. You will get each 128 character into variable "var".

You may use your preferred delimiter to print or use it for further processing.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat yourTextFile | while read -r -n 128 var  ; do
    printf "\n$var"
done
```

You may use it as below at command line:

```
while read -r -n 128 var  ; do printf "\n$var" ; done < yourTextFile
```

Comment: You can remove the `cat` and have `<yourTextFile` after `done` instead. Looks neater, and avoids forking off `cat` and setting up a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

No, the utility will not write anything to standard output.  The [standard specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) of it says specifically that standard output in not used.

If you used `split`, you would need to concatenate the created files, inserting a delimiter in between them.

If you just want to insert a delimiter every *N* th line, you may use GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed '0~3a\-----\' file
```

This inserts a line containing `-----` every 3rd line.

Answer (score 0):

To divide the file into chunks, separated by newlines, and write to stdout, use fold:

```
cat yourfile.txt | fold -w 128
```

...will write to stdout in "chunks" of 128 chars.

Comment: Btw, if you also want a delimiter (in addition to newline) add |sed -e 's/$/<delim>/' or etc.